# Las opciones select de una pagina al redireccionarse desde la pagina y volver atrás se recarguen

Tags: javascript, php, html, mysql, css

tengo un proyecto que estoy haciendo en el cual tengo una pagina de productos con un select y algunas opciones que al retroceder a la pagina previa o ir a la pagina siguiente pero luego regresar no se recarga.
Es decir sucede esto:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Yo deseo que al cambiar de pagina desde la misma pagina, refrescarla o cerrarla y volverla a abrir el select mantenga la opción 'Sabores disponibles'.
Pero yo al tocar por ejemplo en el nav para ir a la sección de 'Nosotros' y luego regresar atrás desde la misma pestaña queda cargada una opción del select si es que lo utilice.
Sucede asi:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Selecciono una opcion del select
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Toco en el enlace a la sección nosotros desde la misma pestaña pero presiono para volver a la pagina anterior.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y al volver la pagina se carga con la opcion del select que presione antes de irme a otra pestaña pero no figura la opción seleccionada por defecto que es 'Sabores disponibles' como la primera vez que se entra a la pagina.

```
<select id="stock" class="custom-select">                             
  <option selected="" value="" disabled=""> Sabores Disponibles</option>
  <option value="6">Rainbow</option>
  <option value="1">Purple Rain</option>
  <option value="2">Blue Razz</option>
  <option value="4">Orange Dream</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Puedes compartirnos el código que estas usando para el SELECT? asi podremos ayudarte más rapido

Comment: Ya lo hice hermano

Comment: Abajo ya hay una respuesta que puedes probar, pero tambien como observación, prueba cambiando esta linea: `<option selected="" value="" disabled="">` de esta forma: `<option selected value="">`

Answer (score 0):

Lo que pasa es que existe un caché llamada [bfcache](https://web.dev/bfcache/) que guarda las páginas que están en la pila de navegación, de esta manera al ir hacia adelante o hacia atrás no hace un llamado al servidor sino que muestra la página almacenada en dicho caché, incluso almancenado los datos ingresados a inputs y selects

Una posible solución es usar el evento [pageshow](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/pageshow_event) para detectar mediante el atributo [persisted](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/PageTransitionEvent/persisted) si la página está en caché o no, y si lo está obligar a hacer un reload o reset al form

```
window.addEventListener( "pageshow", function ( event ) {
  if ( event.persisted ) {
    //window.location.reload();
    document.querySelectorAll('form').forEach(e=> e.reset()); //reseta todos los forms
  }
});
```